# Cannot play videos in VLC

Tags: video, vlc

I am unable to play videos on VLC media player,when I get the videos from my friends through pen drive and then copy to my machine , I am unable to play videos on my machine The VLC opens but nothing appears on the VLC screen , Is anyone facing such problems , It does not also give any error. 
  **If anyone had such problem ??**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have the same problem with Dash > Videos application?

Comment: @MehmetMertYidiran Yes,but the same file works fine with windows machine

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Try this. I believe you can find it in the Software center as well. It should allow you to watch every format, mkv, avi....